# Ace Editor: Lock or Readonly Code Segment

Tags: user-interface, editor, ace-editor, readonly-attribute

Using the Ace Code Editor can I lock or make readonly a segment of code but still allow other lines of code to be written or edited during a session?

Comment: Do you need just one segment or many? can full segment be deleted? If selection includes part of readonly segment and user presses delete, should the rest of selected text be deleted?

Answer (score 22):

Here is the start of a solution:

```
$(function() {
    var editor     = ace.edit("editor1")
        , session  = editor.getSession()
        , Range    = require("ace/range").Range
        , range    = new Range(1, 4, 1, 10)
        , markerId = session.addMarker(range, "readonly-highlight");

    session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    editor.keyBinding.addKeyboardHandler({
        handleKeyboard : function(data, hash, keyString, keyCode, event) {
            if (hash === -1 || (keyCode <= 40 && keyCode >= 37)) return false;

            if (intersects(range)) {
                return {command:"null", passEvent:false};
            }
        }
    });

    before(editor, 'onPaste', preventReadonly);
    before(editor, 'onCut',   preventReadonly);

    range.start  = session.doc.createAnchor(range.start);
    range.end    = session.doc.createAnchor(range.end);
    range.end.$insertRight = true;

    function before(obj, method, wrapper) {
        var orig = obj[method];
        obj[method] = function() {
            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            return wrapper.call(this, function(){
                return orig.apply(obj, args);
            }, args);
        }

        return obj[method];
    }

    function intersects(range) {
        return editor.getSelectionRange().intersects(range);
    }

    function preventReadonly(next, args) {
        if (intersects(range)) return;
        next();
    }
});
```

see it working in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bzwheeler/btsxgena/

The major working pieces are:

1. create start and end ace anchors which track the location of a 'readonly' portion as the document around it changes.
2. create a range to encapsulate the anchors
3. add a custom keyhandler to check if the current impending keypress will affect the readonly range and cancel it if so.
4. add custom paste/cut handlers to protect against right-click menu and browser menu cut/paste actions

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what's going on in the 'before' function, but I know that 'origArgs' is never defined and causes 'preventReadOnly' to puke when it tries to call next() after a cut or paste.

Comment: Good catch!  I edited the before() implementation to use `.call` and to pass along `args` and not `origArgs` which was undefined as you noticed.

Comment: what is addKeyboardHandler doing here? pls explain.

Comment: How to make multiple lines readonly. By passing arrayof range i.e start and end.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by listening to the `exec` events:

```
// Prevent editing first and last line of editor
editor.commands.on("exec", function(e) { 
  var rowCol = editor.selection.getCursor();
  if ((rowCol.row === 0) || ((rowCol.row + 1) === editor.session.getLength())) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

Source: https://jsfiddle.net/tripflex/y0huvc1b/

Comment: While this approach is nice and simple, the main problem with it is that it does not prevent you from removing the line break between first and second line, making it impossible to edit after that. Also, if you move your cursor using arrow keys, it gets stuck on first and last lines.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something else easier and more reliable to prevent range to be modified (check it!)

```
var old$tryReplace = editor.$tryReplace;
editor.$tryReplace = function(range, replacement) {
    return intersects(range)?null:old$tryReplace.apply(this, arguments);                        
}
var session = editor.getSession();
var oldInsert = session.insert;
session.insert = function(position, text) {
    return oldInsert.apply(this, [position, outsideRange(position)?text:""]);
}
var oldRemove = session.remove;
session.remove = function(range) {
    return intersects(range)?false:oldRemove.apply(this, arguments);                        
}
var oldMoveText = session.moveText;
session.moveText = function(fromRange, toPosition, copy) {
    if (intersects(fromRange) || !outsideRange(toPosition)) return fromRange;
    return oldMoveText.apply(this, arguments)
}

outsideRange = function (position) {
    var s0 = range.start;
    if (position.row < s0.row || (position.row == s0.row && position.column <= s0.column)) return true; // position must be before range.start
    var e0 = range.end;
    if (position.row > e0.row || (position.row == e0.row && position.column >= e0.column)) return true; // or after range.end
    return false;
}
intersects = function(withRange) {
    var e = withRange.end, s0 = range.start, s = withRange.start, e0 = range.end;
    if (e.row < s0.row || (e.row == s0.row && e.column <= s0.column)) return false; // withRange.end must be before range.start
    if (s.row > e0.row || (s.row == e0.row && s.column >= e0.column)) return false; // or withRange.start must be after range.end
    return true;
}
```