# Ace Editor deleting addKeyboardHandler

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am using an open source editor called firepad in a web app. The underlying text editor is Ace. I found another post here explaining how to create a readOnly block of code in Ace editor: [Ace Editor: Lock or Readonly Code Segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24958589/ace-editor-lock-or-readonly-code-segment)

This code works for me to make a specified segment readonly, however I want to be able to remove the readOnly restriction. I can delete the ace Marker that denotes the locked are, but I still can't type in the range. I would like to delete the keyboard handler. This is what my code looks like:

```
    editor.keyBinding.addKeyboardHandler({
        handleKeyboard : function(data, hash, keyString, keyCode, event) {
            if (hash === -1 || (keyCode <= 40 && keyCode >= 37)) return false;

            if (intersects(range)) {
                return {command:"null", passEvent:false};
            }
        }
    });
```

I can't find any documentation on the addKeyboardHandler method online. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `removeKeyboardHandler` method to remove it https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/f757c8568/lib/ace/keyboard/keybinding.js#L80

```
var kb = { handleKeyboard : function() {...} }
editor.keyBinding.addKeyboardHandler(kb) // add kb
editor.keyBinding.removeKeyboardHandler(kb) // remove kb
```